# CarrierWave::SanitizedFileの @original_filename の扱いについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

`CarrierWave`のuploaderを持つ`Voice`というモデルがあり

```
class Voice < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :sound, SoundUploader
end
```

これにファイルのアップロードは正常に行えたようなのですが、`CarrierWav::SanitizedFile`の`@original_filename`の扱いがよくわかりません。

```
pry(main)> voice.sound.file
=> #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f94cbfc4d58
 @content_type="audio/x-wav",
 @file="/Users/ironsand/dev/nativephrase/public/uploads/voice/sound/21/something.wav",
 @original_filename=nil>
```

と`@original_filename`が`nil`になってるにもかかわらず

```
pry(main)> voice.sound.file.original_filename
=> "something.wav"
```

のように値が取得できます。

ここで呼び出してるのがインスタンスメソッドではなく`original_filename`というメソッドだと言うことはわかったのですが、インスタンス変数の`@original_filename`が`nil`のままにされているのかよくわかりませんでした。

何か`nil`のままにしておくことで利点があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nil` にしておくことに利点があるのではなく、
ファイルをアップロードするときに使っているだけである、と推察できます。
ファイルがストレージにあるときは、そこからファイル名が取得できるので、`nil`なのではないかと。

```
def file=(file)
  if file.is_a?(Hash)
    @file = file["tempfile"] || file[:tempfile]
    @original_filename = file["filename"] || file[:filename]
    @content_type = file["content_type"] || file[:content_type] || file["type"] || file[:type]
  else
    @file = file
    @original_filename = nil
    @content_type = nil
  end
end
```

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L288-L298

ただ、実行時に一時的にファイル名を書き換えることに使えそうだ、とは思います。

Comment: なるほど、既にファイルが存在していたら使わない変数なのですね。ありがとうございます。